# Extract a string after a number of forward slashes from inside a string

Tags: python, linux, string

Hy have a string which corresponds to a file location in linux, i want to extract just the part of it that corresponds to the username and that always comes after the 6th forward slash and then store it in a new string variable:

```
str1 = "/usr/share/nginx/website/orders/jim/17jkyu.xlsx"
n = 0
user = ','

for ch in str1:
    if ch == '/':
        n += 1
    if n == 6:
        user.join(ch)
    if n == 7:
        break

print(user + '\n')
```

In this case i want to extract jim and put it into the string user.
So far is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string then pull the index value.

```
str1 = "/usr/share/nginx/website/orders/jim/17jkyu.xlsx"
user = str1.split('/')[6]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `split` Python built-in function over the `/` symbol, and select the 7th element:

```
str1.split('/')[6]
```

Comment: Logically author has to accept your answer as best answer..Because you posted First...here +1 from my side :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if n=6 and the current char is not `/`, set user to an empty string and concat the character.

```
str1 = "/usr/share/nginx/website/orders/jim/17jkyu.xlsx"
n = 0
user = ''

for ch in str1:
    if ch == '/':
        n += 1
    if n == 7:
        break
    if n == 6 and ch != '/':
        user += ch

print(user)
```

Output

```
jim
```

Comment: This one is really good to know, so i know how it can be done with my line of thought.